# KDTree and BVH trees - retrieve info

Tags: python

Apparently, Blender can create those structures internally for different purposes.

I have noticed you can use them later to find things like intersections, but can we access somehow the nodes and the data of each tree in any way?

I have a 3d scene that I want to use in a game later on and I would like to use one of those tree structures to render it in game, so if I could get this info already from blender without me having to create an implementation for it, it would be great.

Comment: do you mind using animation nodes? they have such a node. And sverchok as well.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I'm currently using python for blender and I would not mind using animation nodes, but I though the information exposed was similar. What I need in the end is to be able to extract the internal information of the KD/BHV tree